# Why does this set of apt commands work when run line by line, but not when run as a script?

Tags: apt, bash, scripts

I can run this line by line on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 instance in Digital Ocean but I when I give it executable permissions `chmod +x` and run it I get failed attempts at running different parts of the script.

```
sudo apt-get -y install nginx git libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev gdebi-core
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('devtools', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')\""
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')\""
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('XML', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')\""
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "5 0 * * * Rscript /root/transit-tracker/scripts_in_testing/download_gtfs.R ") | crontab -
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * Rscript /root/transit-tracker/scripts_in_testing/get_tidy_gps.R ") | crontab -
wget https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi -n shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb 
sudo sed -i 's/  listen 3838;/  listen 80;/' /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
# then reboot
```

In response I get;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package
Executing: /tmp/tmp.EeBdzAP95F/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
" not a key ID: skipping57CBB651716619E084DAB9
E: Invalid operation update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package r-base
E: Unable to locate package r-base-dev
E: Unable to locate package gdebi-core
-su: R: command not found
-su: R: command not found
-su: R: command not found
-su: R: command not found
-su: R: command not found
'rontab: invalid option -- '
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
'rontab: invalid option -- '
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
--2017-05-08 22:39:38--  https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb%0D
Resolving download3.rstudio.org (download3.rstudio.org)... 52.85.90.213, 52.85.90.39, 52.85.90.98, ...
Connecting to download3.rstudio.org (download3.rstudio.org)|52.85.90.213|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-05-08 22:39:38 ERROR 404: Not Found.

sudo: gdebi: command not found
: No such file or directoryserver/shiny-server.conf
```

Comment: Is your file maybe having Windows line-endings(CR+LF) instead of Unix line-endings (LF only)? You can check that with `file FILENAME` or examine unprintable characters with `cat -A FILENAME`.

Comment: yes I believe, `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: See [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (\n) in a Bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/4518341)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash File Unable to locate package when new line is added](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180771/bash-file-unable-to-locate-package-when-new-line-is-added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you confirmed in the comments, your script has been written on a Windows system and contains Windows-style (CR+LF) line endings instead of Unix-style (LF), which would be necessary.

To easily convert the line endings of text files between DOS/Windows and Unix style, install a package named `dos2unix`:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

It comes with two commands, `dos2unix` to convert a Windows text file to Unix format, and `unix2dos` to convert a Unix text file to Windows format.

In your case, simply run

```
dos2unix FILENAME
```

replacing `FILENAME` with your actual script file name, and it should run fine after that.