# Bash File Unable to locate package when new line is added

Tags: apt, 18.04, bash

When building a bash file to execute I keep getting an error after adding a new line. I have tried moving some lines around or removing some of the packages but it will results in the same error. In the file if I was to remove 3 and 4 it there will no longer be an error.

```
E: Unable to locate package <package>
```

The bash file looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y python3-pip build-essential python3-dev python3-setuptools gcc sshpass
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release software-properties-common dirmngr
sudo apt-get update
```

The output with the error

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                  
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                            
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]        
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                      
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (189 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sshpass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dirmngr
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                  
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                            
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]        
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                      
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (209 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: But it installs just fine if I use just the first line. It seems whatever package I put at the end of each line throws an error.

Comment: no need for that last update. Its also good to upgrade you system before installing anything

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` should be the first command in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what happens is that you have some Windows-style line endings in your file. Maybe the file was copied from a Windows system at some point, or you are using a text editor that uses Windows-style line endings by default? Anyway, I am able to reproduce the behavior if I add such line endings in a similar file.

One way to fix it is to use the `dos2unix` command to change all line endings in the file to unix-style line endings (just `\n` instead of `\r\n` at the end of each line). First install it:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

Then run it on your file, if the filename is myfile.sh then just do this:

```
dos2unix myfile.sh
```

which should give an output like this:

```
dos2unix: converting file myfile.sh to Unix format...
```

and after that your script should work, you should no longer get the "E: Unable to locate package" errors.

The opposite command `unix2dos` is also available, you can use that if you want the problem to come back again. :-)

To play with it further, you can use for example `hexdump -C myfile.sh` to look at the difference before/after running `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` on the file.